# Can't open View->DBA Menu in SQL Developer (Oracle 12C Standard Edition Installed)

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper, oracle12c

I have installed Oracle 12C Standard Edition. Everything works fine there. I have also connected the Oracle SQL Developer Client 4.0. From that I can access the tables, indexes etc.

I am trying to see the tablespace details from SQL Developer Client by clicking the View -> DBA menu. By clicking this menu, nothing is getting opened.

Through EM I can able to see those. But I want to see through SQL developer.

I am not sure, whether I need to do any settings, so that the View -> DBA menu can be opened.

Attached Screenshot for reference:

Here I am selecting the DBA option under View Menu

[image]

But I don't see any DBA related window.

[image]

Comment: You don't have a new panel on the left-hand side called "DBA"? Somewhere under the "Connections" panel?

Comment: not under connections tab...under View Menu, there is DBA Sub menu...when i clicked that, nothing happened.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Selecting the View->DBA menu item displays the "DBA" panel, on the left side of the SQL Developer window and somewhere below the "Connections" panel; the exact placement may vary a bit depending on which other panels you have displayed:

[image]

You then need to add a connection in that window' if you click the green plus sign you can choose an existing connection to add to this panel. Once you've done that you can expand the sections to see the tablespaces:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for you reply. I have edited my question. Also added the screenshot. After the clicking the DBA menu also, i dint see any DBA windows in sql developer.

Comment: OK, I see you have your Connections section minimised to the left border; but even starting from that position you should see the DBA section in the left border too after picking the menu item. Are you on the current release, 4.0.2.15, or one of the earlier versions of 4.0?

Comment: The version is 4.0.1.14

Comment: Hmm, well works for me in that version too, whether the connections are minimised or not. I'm running both versions under Windows 7. Not sure what to suggest, apart from reinstalling, or installing the later version to see if that fixes it anyway. Since it *should* be working, maybe you need to ask [on the forum](https://forums.oracle.com/community/developer/english/development_tools/application_development_in_pl_sql/sql_developer_(not_for_general_sql_plsql_questions)), or raise a service request. Strange...

Comment: I am using Windows Server 2012 R2. Is that anyway related to the issue.?

Comment: @RobinHood - I don't know. I wondered if disabling the feature could do this, but no, it doesn't appear in the menu if you do. The only similar effect I can get is to undock the DBA panel and then drag it off screen.  If you Alt-tab do you have a separate process called 'DBA - editor'? Does the main window lose focus when you pick the menu item? If so, does Window->Configure Window->Dock make it appear, or Window->Reset Windows to Factory Settings (which has a wider impact!)?

Comment: In this version 4.0.1.14, i have tried a lot and i cant able to see the "DBA" menu. So i have installed another version of SQL Developer.

Answer (score 135):

I faced same problem, solved by: Windows->reset windows to factory settings. 
After that everything worked fine

Comment: Hehehe, it was so simple

Comment: Magically help me even now in version 17.

Comment: Works on 19.2.1 - Linux version

Comment: Still works on 21.2.1.204 on Windows

Answer (score 4):

goto Menu of the Sql Developer windows-->Reset the Windows to Factory Settings

and then goto view menu ----> click DBA

it works.(Version 17.2.0.188)

Answer (score 0):

**I have got this problem a month ago.**

1-Go to C:\Documents and Settings\"your profile"\Application Data\SQL Developer

2-Save your connection : o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.0.22.49.35

3-delete the C:\Documents and Settings\"your profile"\Application Data\SQL Developer

4-restart SQL developer, will recreate the same directory structure.

5-exit SQL developer

6-copy the backup "o.jdeveloper.db.connection.11.1.1.0.22.49.35" to 
C:\Documents and Settings\"your profile"\Application Data\SQL Developer

7- you should be able to see the connection tab

Answer (score 0):

1.) Save your current SQL connection xml file located in windows 10: C:\Users\"youruseraccount"\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\systemXXXXX\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.xxxxxx

2.)Now delete your SQL Developer Folder and sqldeveloper folder located in:
C:\Users\"youruseraccount"\AppData\Roaming\

3.)Now delete the main sqldeveloper folder containing the actual SQL developer application files.This would be located wherever you initially unzipped the  SQLDeveloper download.

4.)Download the latest version of SQL Developer and unzip wherever you like.

5.)Launch SQL developer and specify your JDK location.

6.)Copy your connections xml file to your roaming SQL Developer directory here:
C:\Users\"youruseraccount"\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\systemXXXXXX)\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.xxxxxx

7.)Launch SQL Developer and your DBA view should now be available after selecting view -> DBA

Comment: Formatting your answer would surely make it more attractive