# SQL Developer won't show the connections Tab

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

So SQL Developer won't show the connections tab no matter what I do. 
I've tried going through the "view" tab and clicking into the "connections" and I've also tried clicking the new button. I've also tried an uninstall/reinstall, but nothing.

It's probably something simple, but I'm fairly new to it, can anyone direct me or provide any advice? 
Any help is really appreciated :)

Comment: try Windows > Reset Windows to Factory Settings

Comment: Is there any way to do it without a reset? I can't back up the rest of my files at the moment

Comment: But it will only reset your windows, it won't close your opened files.

Comment: I  have no clue.  Just a suggestion.  Maybe try Oracle support/community forum?

Comment: find the connections.xml file and delete it - it's probably been corrupted - only do this if the Reset Windows to Factory Settings doesn't fix it first. BTW, this is not MSFT Windows/format/re-install, it's the WINDOWS menu in SQLDev, it has a Reset item which refreshes the desktop layout of SQLDev

Comment: If the connections tab is minimized, then it shows up only if you hover your mouse pointer over the Connections text that shows up vertically on the left most corner of the SQL Developer. Make sure that is not the case as it is easy to miss the vertical Connections text.

Comment: The Reset windows to factory settings worked @OldProgrammer. So thank you very much for that solution!
Thank you to the rest of the solutions too, I'll be sure to give them a go in the future if I encounter this issue again without success!

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Cant open View->DBA Menu in SQL Developer (Oracle 12C Standard Edition Installed)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24143886/cant-open-view-dba-menu-in-sql-developer-oracle-12c-standard-edition-installed)

Answer (score 137, accepted):

You can go to the upper tab "WINDOW" and then click "Reset Windows to factory settings".

Comment: This works and doesn't forget all connections credentials

Comment: perfect thanks it was annoying issue with sql Developer

Comment: Exactly what i needed. Thanks

Comment: This answer saved me so much time! Thanks...

Comment: Yippee! Fixed it in a flash! - BTW, just to reassure anyone who's wondering; the windows it refers to are the SQL developer windows (panes?) - Not MS Windows (tm)!!!

Answer (score 10):

1.) Save your current SQL connection xml file located in windows 7/8/10: C:\Users\"youruseraccount"\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\systemXXXXX\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.xxxxxx

2.)Now delete your SQL Developer Folder and sqldeveloper folder located in: C:\Users\"youruseraccount"\AppData\Roaming\

3.)Now delete the main sqldeveloper folder containing the actual SQL developer application files.This would be located wherever you initially unzipped the SQLDeveloper download.

4.)Download the latest version of SQL Developer and unzip wherever you like.

5.)Launch SQL developer and specify your JDK location.

6.)Copy your connections xml file to your roaming SQL Developer directory here: C:\Users\"youruseraccount"\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\systemXXXXXX)\o.jdeveloper.db.connection.xxxxxx

7.)Launch SQL Developer and your DBA view should now be available after selecting view -> DBA

Comment: You don't even have to re-install - I did steps 1, 2, and 3, then simply re-launched sqldeveloper; the folders you deleted will be re-created; then just place your o.jdeveloper.db.connection.xxxx in the correct location. And re-launch sqldeveloper again.

Answer (score 10):

1 ) Select the **Windows** Menu

[image]

2 ) Choose the option **Reset Windows to Factory Settings**

[image]

3 ) Oracle SQL Developer automatically closed and reopened.

Answer (score 2):

Search for the file - windowinglayoutDefault.xml and delete it, and restart SQL Developer.

This file should be present inside a system folder at

```
windowuserPath\AppData\Roaming\SQL Developer\
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the similar issue with SQL Developer 4.2, one fine day all the connections pane on left vanished, tried couple options unsuccessfully.

Remedy is 
1) Installation of newer version of SQL Developer to the folder of your choice with newer java JDK
2) Import the preference from previous version. DID the TRICK... Good Luck

- Rajarao

Answer (score 1):

For me, it worked in the following way:
I just deleted the folder where I had extracted the zip folder and then re-extracted it and then ran sqldeveloper.exe

Answer (score 1):

[image]

This worked for me!!, No need of recreating the connections.

Comment: Yup, that's the easiest way.

Answer (score 0):

I exported all my connection to a json file. Then imported the one disappeared and it worked.